# Find row and column index of maximum value in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I wish to find the maximum element-value of a matrix and it's location (in row and column id in the matrix).

I am using the following function to return the row and column of the matrix.

This seems like a bad hack -- it's the sort of thing where i'm probably missing a native method.  Is there a better / *more R* way?

Here's my function:

```
matxMax <- function(mtx)
{
    colmn <- which(mtx == max(mtx)) %/% nrow(mtx) + 1
    row <- which(mtx == max(mtx)) %% nrow(mtx)
    return( matrix(c(row, colmn), 1))
}
```

I use is as follows:

```
mm <- matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)
maxCords <- matxMax(mm)
mm[maxCords]
```

Comment: the solution is the same, but i did search and i think there's a case for having a solution under both max and min (which i had remembered to search for min as well). Also, the function (though redundant in this case) may be of some pedagogical value.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You could do

```
## Some data
set.seed(123)
mm <- matrix(rbinom(40, 20, 0.5), 8, 5)
mm
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    9   10    8   11   11
# [2,]   12   10    6   11   12
# [3,]    9   14    9   10    6
# [4,]   13   10   14   11   10
# [5,]   13   11   13    9   12
# [6,]    6   10   11    8    8
# [7,]   10    7   11   14    9
# [8,]   13   13   16   13    8

which(mm == max(mm), arr.ind = TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   8   3
```

Comment: is there any way to find location of the second max value? second max value could be same as the first max value and in that case i would like to get location of the second max value which will be exactly same as the first max value.

Comment: @user2543622, have you tried the proposed solution on an example in your setup? The proposed solution provides the list of all elements of the matrix that are equal to the maximum. So if there are ties you'll get them all.

Comment: @user2543622, here's a top-ten list: `which(mm >= tail(sort(mm), n=10)[1], arr.ind=TRUE)`